# How to wrap a function to add a new parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I hava a component that need a function like  property where send a parameter 'value'

```
function myLoadOptions(value)  {
    fetch( (...)
    .then( (...) return data.options)
}


<Component
loadOptions = myLoadOptions

/>
```

but I need to add o wrap the function to add new parameters like this:

```
function myLoadOptions(table, value)  {
    fetch( (...)
    .then( (...) return data.options)

}
let table = 'customers';
<Component
loadOptions = myLoadOptions(table)
/>
```

but it's not working, loadOptions does not read by the table, there is a wrap way to do it ?

More about original component:
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

```
import { Async } from 'react-select';

/*
 * assuming the API returns something like this:
 *   const json = [
 *      { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
 *      { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
 *   ]
 */

const getOptions = (input) => {
  return fetch(`/users/${input}.json`)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    }).then((json) => {
      return { options: json };
    });
}

<Async
  name="form-field-name"
  value="one"
  loadOptions={getOptions}
/>
```

Comment: Do request in ComponentDidmount then do SetState, and pass this state in to props of your component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding the first argument to the function, like this:

```
<Component
  loadOptions={myLoadOptions.bind(null, table)}
/>
```

Other option would be a wrapper, like margaretkru suggested, but with a slight change to pass the second argument:

```
<Component loadOptions={(value) => myLoadOptions(table, value) }/>
```

Comment: please read this another solution:   const generateOptionsFunc =  tablename => input => {
  return fetch(..)
}

const loadOptions = generateOptionsFunc("users")
<Component loadOptions={loadOptions} />, is the same?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `render`:

```
let table = 'customers';
...
<Component loadOptions={() => myLoadOptions(table) }/>
```

Comment: thanks , but myLoadoptions need value like parameter..., i've updated my question with information about original component

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. do you need to call `myLoadOptions` and pass the result as `props`?

Comment: not really, the solution is pure javascript , read the another answer